# Remove Parentheses from span with class using JS

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, class, parentheses

While using a audio plugin for wordpress, the span/class automatically adds parentheses around the text, for example:

```
`<span class="songwriter">(Female & Male dialog, Humorous, Storyteller, Cocky, Sassy)</span>`
```

Is there a way to remove the parentheses using JavaScript?

I tried:

```js
$('span.songwriter').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="songwriter">(Female & Male dialog, Humorous, Storyteller, Cocky, Sassy)</span>
```

This now works in the snippet and JSFiddle, but parentheses are still present on the page...https://www.cathydvoiceactor.wolfandkey.com/

Comment: I've converted your posted code into a runnable snippet, though while I'm sure you've included the jQuery library I couldn't include it here without your verification. May I ask that you update the snippet to accurately reflect your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't prevent the html from showing up on the page, you could remove the parentheses using something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.songwriter').forEach(
  (span) => span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(/\(|\)/g, '')
);
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but parentheses are still present on the page. Observe demos on https://www.cathydvoiceactor.wolfandkey.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
// https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js

$('span.songwriter').each(function() {
    $element = $(this);
    $element.html($element.html().replace(/\(|\)/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<span class="songwriter">(Female & Male dialog, Humorous, Storyteller, Cocky, Sassy)</span>

<br/>

<span class="songwriter">(Female & Male dialog, Humorous, Storyteller, Cocky, Sassy)</span>

<br/>

<span class="songwriter">(Female & Male dialog, Humorous, Storyteller, Cocky, Sassy)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because of a typo, and had you looked at your developer console the error should have been somewhat obvious, see below:

```js
$('span.songwriter').text(function(text) {
  return text.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="songwriter">(Female & Male dialog, Humorous, Storyteller, Cocky, Sassy)</span>
```

The reason that `text.replace` is not a function is because `text` isn't what you think it is; the first argument is the index of the current element in the collection returned by jQuery, and the second is the existing text:

```js
$('span.songwriter').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="songwriter">(Female & Male dialog, Humorous, Storyteller, Cocky, Sassy)</span>
```

When jQuery doesn't work as you expect it's always worth checking the – excellent, and easily referenced – jQuery documentation to see why.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:
- [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text)